# Text overlay in wrapfig

Tags: two-column, multicol, wrapfigure

I would like put a figure with the size of the column, so that the text is starting after the image caption but i'm not able to do it (text overlay with the next column Figure 1).

Right now i'm using multicol package and i tried to switch to twocolumn but i'm not able to do it since i need tu put an image at top right of the paper (rapresented in black) and some info on the bottom like in Figure 1 .

[image]

Here's the code I attempted so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{acsyellow}{RGB}{255,241,204}

\usepackage{framed} 
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!25}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} %Used for including image on top right corner
\usepackage{epsfig}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\Large \@title}

  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

\renewenvironment{abstract}
     {
    \vfill%
      \list{}{
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{.3cm}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
      \vfill%
      }%
      \item\relax}
 {\endlist}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} 

\title{Hammett linear free energy relationship \vspace{0.3cm}}
\author{ \large Name Surname textsuperscript{[a]}}
\date{}
\newcommand{\affiliation}{
    \begin{itemize}
    
    %   Please delete lines not applicapble             
    
        \item[{[a]}] info, Info info\\
        Info\\
        E-mail: Info\\
        Info
    \end{itemize}
}
 
\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.east|-0,2cm) {\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{images/logo.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace{-1.0cm}

    \begin{figure} [!b]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}{\rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}\footnotesize{\textsf{\affiliation}}}\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{shaded}
        \begin{abstract}
            \textbf{Abstract}. \blindtext[2]
        \end{abstract}
    \end{shaded}


    \section*{Some dummy text}
       \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{wrapfigure}{h}{\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/reaction.eps}
                \caption{Hello!}
            \end{wrapfigure}
            
            \blindtext[2]
        \end{multicols}

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{citazioni}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wrapfigure doesn't have an `h`option,  just `l`  `r` and is for wrapping text around the figure so doesn't really do anything useful if you specify `{\linewidth}` as that leaves no space for the text so it just makes tex try to fit words in to the 0pt space to the side of the figure

Comment: Okok now i understand why it doesn't function, thank you for the explaination! Do you have any suggestion on an alternative method that i can use? @David Carlisle

Comment: probably just use minipage and `\captionof{figure}{Hello!}` (`capt-of` package)